# Freezing basemap using cx_freeze

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am  working on script and I´d like to freeze it for use in computers who haven´t got python installed-

The script is running fine but when I freeze it using cx_freeze an error appears.

at the end of the message says

OSError:proj data directory not found. Expecting it at: C:\python34........mpl_toolkits\basemap\data

Is the data not included in the build directory created by cx_freeze ?

I am using the following script for freezing, the 'executable'

base = None

```
def find_data_file(pyproj):
    if getattr(sys,'XXXXs.exe',False):
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.aaEjecutable.py)
    else:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(datadir,pyproj)

if (sys.platform == "win32"):
   base = "Win32GUI"

exe = Executable(
        script = "Conver.py",  
        icon = "logo4.ico",
        targetName = "XXXXs.exe", 
        base = base
        )
includefiles = ["Logo1.jpg","Logo2R.jpg","Logo2R.jpg","logo4.ico",
                (('C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits'),("mpl_toolkits"))] 
setup(
    name = "Conver",
    version = "V3",
    description = "conve",
    author = "Jose ",
    options = {"build_exe": {"include_files":includefiles}}, 
    executables = [exe]
 )
```

I think that something is wrong with it. I must include the basemap but I dont't know how to do it

I cannot go foward. The python script runs fine but I can use it in a computer with no python installed.

Comment: related questions: [Can´t freeze a script with matplotlib basemap and cx_freeze](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286624/can%C2%B4t-freeze-a-script-with-matplotlib-basemap-and-cx-freeze), [cx_freeze, mpl_toolkits/basemap/ how include the data folder in the build library.zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662025/cx-freeze-mpl-toolkits-basemap-how-include-the-data-folder-in-the-build-librar) and a possible solution [Matplotlib-users: basemap and py2exe](http://sourceforge.net/p/matplotlib/mailman/message/24838444/)

Comment: That's mine. I can't solve the problem using the advises in stackexchange

Comment: and the possible solution ?